# android error (Expecting member declaration)

Tags: android

I'm having issues getting past this point.  when I type private EditText nameText; I don't get an import and the application acts like it won't recognize the command.

```
package com.chriskehl.storybook

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class storyBook : AppCompatActivity() {

 private EditText nameField;  // expecting member declaration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_book)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**import EditText manually**   `import android.widget.EditText;`

then clean your project

option **Build->clean**